# Child class with no table in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a class "Identity", mapped to a table with NHibernate.

Then I have a few other classes, Candidate, Employee, ... in a separate assembly.
Those classes are mapped as well and each have a property of type Identity.

Now in the DB some new table were added and are referencing the table mapped from Identity. Those new table represent data that should only exist in the same assembly as Candidate, Employee, ....

So my setting is like this :

- new tables with foreign key to "identity table"
- I need to map those tables to new classes in an assembly which depends on (thus which cannot be depended of) the assembly where identity is

I don't know how I can handle this mapping.

I though I could create a new class inheriting Identity, but then this class would have "scalar" properties or even a "key", this class is just a place holder for a set of one-to-many properties.

How can I work arround this?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use *table per subclass* inheritance strategy, combined with mapping all the properties of your sub table as a component.

You would end up with classes like `IdentityForTable1 : Identity`, `IdentityForTable2 : Identity`, having respectively the properties `ComponentForTable1 PropertyForTable1`, `ComponentForTable2 PropertyForTable2`.

See this [page](https://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance) for inheritance strategies, and look for *table per subclass*. You should then map properties in each `joined-subclass` as a [component](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html).

Comment: The issue is, I don't want to add new tables for the subclasses. If I do add them, they would just hold an ID (equal to Identity's one) and those table woulmdn't even correspond to the foreign key definition of the tables which were previously added.

Comment: You should not have to add new tables with what I propose, you would use the other new table already added. I you need more details, you should edit your question to give more information, like db schema samples, current entities samples and their mappings, ...